# UIStoryboardSegue sourceViewController above destinationViewController

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue

I want to "slide out" my view controller above the `destinationViewController` with a segue. This is my code:

```
override func perform()
{
    let src = self.sourceViewController
    let dst = self.destinationViewController

    dst.view.superview?.insertSubview(src.view, aboveSubview: dst.view)
    src.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25,
        delay: 0.0,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut,
        animations: {
            src.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(src.view.frame.size.width * -1, 0)
        },
        completion: { finished in
            src.presentViewController(dst, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    )
}
```

The slide looks good, however the destinationViewController is all black during the animation, when the animation is completed the destinationViewController is shown correctly.

How can I make it display during segue animation?

EDIT:

solved it:

```
override func perform()
{
    let src = self.sourceViewController
    let dst = self.destinationViewController

    src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, belowSubview: src.view)
    dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25,
        delay: 0.0,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut,
        animations: {
            src.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(src.view.frame.size.width * -1, 0)
        },
        completion: { finished in
            src.presentViewController(dst, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class FirstCustomSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        // Assign the source and destination views to local variables.
        var firstVCView = self.sourceViewController.view as UIView!
        var secondVCView = self.destinationViewController.view as UIView!

        // Get the screen width and height.
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

        // Specify the initial position of the destination view.
        secondVCView.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth, 0.0, screenWidth, screenHeight)

        // Access the app's key window and insert the destination view above the current (source) one.
        let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
        window?.insertSubview(secondVCView, aboveSubview: firstVCView)


        // Animate the transition.
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
            firstVCView.frame = CGRectOffset(firstVCView.frame, -screenWidth, -0.0)
            secondVCView.frame = CGRectOffset(secondVCView.frame, -screenWidth, -0.0)

            }) { (Finished) -> Void in
                self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController as! UIViewController,
                    animated: false,
                    completion: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a Storyboard ID to your ViewController.